# Typescript generic string contatenation

Tags: typescript

Consider the following function:

```
function Foo<T extends string>(name: T) {
    return `${name}:FOO`
}
```

Then used this way:

```
const str = Foo("bar")
```

Ideally, I'd like the type of `str` method to be `bar:FOO` instead of `string`. As this method is simply an enum creator.

How can I achieve that in typescript?

Comment: Note: I tried the `&` operator, by typing the return type of `Foo` to `T & ":FOO"`. But this doesn't do what I expected

Comment: This is not possible in typescript. You can't do compile time string manipulations

Comment: Enums are intended to be compile-time deterministic options. An "enum creator" defeats that purpose.

Comment: This function is usually used in Redux, to generate request/fail/success actions based on a name. The enum is still constant

Comment: I do not think this is possible.

Comment: This is impossible because `Foo('bar')` has return value at runtime, not at compile time.